# C Linked List/Stack w/ void data members issue

Tags: c, memory, struct, stack, void-pointers

So I was playing with stacks and  made a generic Stack.h file and a Stack.c file which define the list and its functions, respectively, and when I try it out (stackdemo.c) it crashes when I pop from the list. I tried using `void **` node members, being cautious with memory leaks, etc but nothing gets me past that. I am using the MinGW 32-bit gcc compiler and g++ for linking for Windows 7, giving no warnings.

I have a hunch that I might have to realloc the `NODE` struct every time `push` is called because the data member gets allocated after the `NODE` struct is, but I don't know how many bytes to allocate. I am assuming that the malloc of the `NODE` struct allocates two pointer variables and nothing more. I am not aware of any current memory leaks.

```
//Stack.h

#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H`
#include "string.h"

typedef struct _Node
{
    size_t size;
    void *data;
    struct _Node *next;
} NODE;
void push(NODE **head, void *data, size_t size);
void pop(NODE **head, void *data);
#endif
```

And stack.c

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

void push(NODE **head, void *data,size_t size)
{
    NODE *temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE*));
    temp->size = size;
    temp->data = malloc(size);
    temp->next = *head;
    memcpy(temp->data,data,size);
    *head = temp;
}
void pop(NODE **head, void *data)
{
    NODE *temp = *head;
    if(temp)
    {
        data = malloc(temp->size);
        memcpy(data,temp->data,temp->size);
        *head = temp->next;
        free(temp->data);
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

The test program:

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include "stdio.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 1;
    NODE *head = NULL;
    while(n)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a number to push or press -1 to pop, 0 to quit:\t");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n > 0)
        {
            push(&head,&n,sizeof(int));
            printf("Pushed %d on the stack",n);
        }
        else if(n == -1)
        {
            int i;
            pop(&head,&i);
            printf("Popped %d from the stack",i);
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes every time it gets to pop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at pop : The following line is not necessary.

```
data = malloc(temp->size);
```

at push :

```
NODE *temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE*));
```

should be

```
NODE *temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

Comment: Why? 'memcpy' does not allocate memory, so I would have to allocate the memory beforehand.

Comment: @user2727804 `pop` will write back to memory that is specified(void *data). It is `i`(pass by &i) in terms of this program.

Comment: Can I assign the struct pointers using `=` like I do with `*head = temp;` ? There might be a size mismatch.

Comment: @user2727804 I don't feel like there are other issues to pop. I think  crash by mixing with C++.

Comment: I think it is in `push`. Do you think I could malloc the whole struct instead of mallocing the blank struct and then mallocing the `void *data`?

Comment: Maybe if I did not allocate correctly, then I could be copying more memory than what is available, crashing the program.

Comment: It doesn't crash now! :)

Comment: I can see now... The sizeof(NODE*) was just the size of a pointer while sizeof(NODE) is the size of the struct.